# Run list of results in parallel in Celery chain

Tags: python, celery, python-3.7, django-celery

Here's the logic I want to implement:

```
1. Get a list of URLs by scraping a home page
2. Get, scrape and store a sublist of URLs in parallel by visiting each link in above list
```

I first tried to create a master task which firstly scraped all the URLs from home page, and then, in a for loop, got sub-URLs:

```
@task
def master_task():
    urls = scrape_list_of_urls()
    job = group([scrape_url_and_save.s(url) for url in urls])  # scrape_url takes around 200ms each URL, and there are thousands of URLs. Hence I want it to run in parallel
    result = job.apply_async()
    result.join()
@task
def scrape_url_and_save(url):
    save_to_db(contents_of_url_by_scraping)
...
def scrape(request):  # In Django
    master_task.delay()
    ...
```

But this results in an error:

> RuntimeError: Never call result.get() within a task!

I'm using Celery 4 inside a Django app. The `master_task` has to be a task since I do not want the user to wait while it scrapes the main page. I'm not sure if my code logic is correct. A better logic would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is similar SO question which resolves the problem with your runtime error. [Link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45491380/3612571)
2. Is there any reason, why is it so complicated? I consider having that many tasks as overcomplicated. Maybe I'm wrong, but the point 3. in your list is redundant and there is no need to store the data in the database at once.

So if I were you, I would do one `master_task` that will spawn for every url `scrape_url.delay(url)` that will do the **scraping** job and will also save the result to the database. It will result in spawning many tasks in queue, and then processing them in parallel will be dependent in the count of your workers.

Comment: I checked that question, but it's not really what I want to use. It's more of a hack than proper code.
2. Well yeah, I can pop out step 3 and directly store data in step 2. That can be ignored.

I was hoping for a solution using chains or something, because there a thousands of URLs and this might cause a very slow performance or a deadlock.

Comment: It looks like you're hoping for some magic. If your task can stuck and cause deadlock, then what do you expect from waiting for task results? I think skipping step 3. and letting step 2. save the data will be appropriate.

Comment: Ah I did not mean it like that, I meant it because of this: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#avoid-launching-synchronous-subtasks

Since there are thousands of URLs, it'll result in a deadlock if the worker pool is exhausted.

Comment: sure, why not to run the tasks in chain as they are now and let them save the data?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way you can achieve desired work-flow - your master task should return a group of subtasks, e.g.

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def master_task(self):
    urls = scrape_list_of_urls()
    job = group((self.app.signature('tasks_module.scrape_url_and_save', (url,)) for url in urls))  
    # run scrape_url_and_save in parallel e.g. using gevent/eventlet worker pool
    return job.delay()
```